# Total bits of accuracy gained per iteration with Newton's Method?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, newton-raphson

With respect to a one dimensional nonlinear equation, how many bits of accuracy are gained per iteration with Newton's method?

I know I can use Newton's method to find an arbitrary root and then just compare the bits of accuracy for each iterative error. However, is there a more general method to prove this regardless of the equation?

Comment: So you want to explore the practical consequences of the quadratic convergence? $e_{n+1}\le Ce_n^2\implies Ce_n\le (Ce_0)^{2^n}$ etc.?

Comment: You should elaborate a bit on what you already know and what you which to know. In particular, it is not clear what you mean when you say " just compare the bits of accuracy for each iterative error".